# Parallel testing with selinium TestNG and selinium

Tags: selenium, testng

Using TestNG and Selenium, can we perform parallel testing with multiple browsers at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **yes**.  TestNG allows you to run in parallel, and each instance of a browser driver is separate and independent from each other, allowing Selenium tests to run parallel to each other.

For more information on how to do this, there are a number of good tutorials available, including this one:
https://www.toolsqa.com/testng/testng-parallel-execution/

Comment: Thank you for your answer,the problem is that all the tests run in parallel but in the same browser, I don't know how I can create a new instance of chrome for every test

Comment: The solution depends on how you are setting up with TestNG.  You will need to make sure you create the new instance in a method annotated with either `@BeforeTest`, or `@BeforeMethod`.  If you share your code I can help you figure it out.